# How to display FBSDKLoginButton in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8, xcode6, facebook-sdk-4.0

how can I properly display my FBSDKLoginButton to my UITableViewCell. I don't have enough reputation to post images so [here's the link to my screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10131270/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20Jul%2013%2C%202015%2C%204.19.29%20PM.png).

As you can see from my screenshot, the logout button is partially hidden. Here's my code snippet for my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
if indexPath.row == 4 { //LOGOUT
        fbLoginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile"]
        fbLoginButton.delegate = self
        fbLoginButton.center = myCell.contentView.center
        myCell.contentView.addSubview(fbLoginButton)
        myCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        myCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the button's frame?

Comment: @matthias I set its center to `fbLoginButton.center = myCell.contentView.center`. I honestly don't know how set its frame. A little help? Thanks :)

Comment: @matthias In `viewDidLoad()` I declared it as: `let fbLoginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()`

Comment: What happens when you set fbLoginButton.center to myCell.center? Are you using a custom TableViewCell?

Comment: @matthias I tried myCell.center and it's still the same. I'm not using a custom TableViewCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to show the facebook logout button properly by this code:

```
if indexPath.row == 4 { //LOGOUT
        fbLoginButton.delegate = self
        fbLoginButton.center = CGPointMake(tableView.bounds.width/2, fbLoginButton.bounds.height / 1.4)
        myCell.addSubview(fbLoginButton)
        myCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        myCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
}
```

I don't know if this is the right way but it works for me. My screenshot now [looks like this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10131270/TableViewCell%20Fb%20Logout%20Button.png).

Answer (score 0):

You should add a **custom** `UITableViewCell`.

I have no code to test, and I'm not sure, but if I'm ok, `FBSDKLoginButton` is a `UIView`. In your custom `UITableViewCell` add a `UIView` of type `FBSDKLoginButton` (Of course, in your custom `UITableViewCell` the button will be an `@IBOutlet`). It should works.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3:

```
fbLoginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.width, height: YourCellHeight)
fbLoginButton.delegate = self
myCell.addSubview(fbLoginButton)
myCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
```